# Private Application IP routing between two countries

Tags: networking, tcp, routes, udp, network-protocols

I was asked a question in my oral exams:

```
You are accessing a website whose webserver is located in country A.
You are in Country B.
You know that the TCP/UDP Packets pass through Country C while travelling from Country B to Country A.
How will you avoid your packets to travel via Country C, and rather select a different route ?
```

Any answers for this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The topology looks like this (I have annotated the webserver as `Z`, below):

```
  new fiber (in ASN 777)
     +-------+
     |       |
Z----A---C---B
     |   |   |
     <INTERNET>
```

### Executive Summary

Since there are no rules otherwise, the *smartest* thing countries A and B could do is purchase a direct fiber run between A and B<sup>1</sup>.  Country B must administer the routers on both sides and announce a small route (something like a `/24` block) in BGP from B's router in country A to B's router in B.  B should obtain a new [ASN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_System_Number) for this purpose (we'll call it ASN 777).

### Important Details

Now ensure that *all* users needing connectivity to Z in country B have a direct connection to an ISP peering with B's intercontinental routers via eBGP<sup>2</sup>.  Country A must ensure that Z is directly connected to an ISP that prefers routes to country B through their router in country A<sup>2</sup>.

The reason this works is because eBGP picks one shortest path based on the number of ISP hops<sup>3</sup>; and all the variables are directly in country B and country A's control.

**END NOTES**

---

1. Even if this is a trans-oceanic fiber run; the biggest requirement is that it does not pass through C's territory (or even close to their allies, if security is very critical).  You really have no control if you pass traffic between the coutries via **any** third party (to include the proxy-suggestion in another answer).  Also understand that dark-fiber probably will not cut it... due to the distances that are usually involved between countries, managed fiber repeaters will be required in-line.
2. All ISPs in question must *refuse* routes for Z and B via any other [ASN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_System_Number), except through ASN 777.  If you are ultra-paranoid (and it's administratively possible), put Z and all users of the data from Z into ASN 777.
3. Technically, ISP hops are measured as [Autonomous System Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_System_Number), which is how eBGP evaluates route preference (lower numbers of ASNs crossed are better routes).

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: use a proxy?

Proxy in country `D`, which you know that packets from `B` to `D` does not go through `C`, and packets from `D` to `A` doesn't go through `C` either. So the route would be:

`B` -> `[E]` -> `D` -> `[F]` -> `A`,

where `E` and `F` are some countries that you can send your packets through.

Is it only me, or is `C` looks like `C`hina? :-)

Comment: Yeah, that could work, after expanding shortcuts like that, this question is much more interesting

Comment: It's a homework question - which means using a proxy is a very high level answer. The answer I would think would be to disallow the AS which serves country C in country B's AS' configuration. Read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(Internet) and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing#Multiple_agents

Answer (score 0):

You could use simple AS path filters so that you only know of a path that does not traverse the undesired AS.